# less-loader parse version number in globalVars wrongly

Tags: webpack, less, less-loader

I'm using webpack 1.12.2, with less-loader version 2.2.3, and less 2.7.3 (i've got some issues that prevent me from upgrading...).

Anyway, i'm trying to add a glovalVars parameter for adding version number to urls (for some cache system).
but when i add this to the webpack config:

```
{"globalVars":{"version_number":"0.5.7"}}
```

and lets say i have this code in my less file:

```
div {
    background-image: url("assets/@{version_number}/images/image.png");
}
```

it results in:

```
div {
    background-image: url("assets/0.5 0.7/images/image.png");
}
```

instead of:

```
div {
    background-image: url("assets/0.5.7/images/image.png");
}
```

really frustrating.
any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me - i only need to change it to:

```
{"globalVars":{"version_number":"\"0.5.7\""}}
```